# How to open new applet window from a applet

Tags: java, applet

how can i open a new applet window from a applet itself?

Answer (score 6):

**To open a new Java window ([`JFrame`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html)) from an applet, see the following extract from the [Java tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html):**

```
//1. Create the frame.
JFrame frame = new JFrame("FrameDemo");

//2. Optional: What happens when the frame closes?
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

//3. Create components and put them in the frame.
//...create emptyLabel...
frame.getContentPane().add(emptyLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

//4. Size the frame.
frame.pack();

//5. Show it.
frame.setVisible(true);
```

**To open a new browser window which also contains an applet [`showDocument(URL, "_blank")`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/applet/AppletContext.html#showDocument(java.net.URL,%20java.lang.String)):**

```
URL url = new URL(getCodeBase().getProtocol(),
                      getCodeBase().getHost(),
                      getCodeBase().getPort(),
                      "/next.html");
getAppletContext().showDocument(url, "_blank");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.ashok.test;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JToolBar;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class ChessBoardWithColumnsAndRows {

    private final JPanel gui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(3, 3));
    private JButton[][] chessBoardSquares = new JButton[8][8];
    private JPanel chessBoard;
    private final JLabel message = new JLabel(
            "Chess Champ is ready to play!");
    private static final String COLS = "ABCDEFGH";

    ChessBoardWithColumnsAndRows() {
        initializeGui();
    }

    public final void initializeGui() {
        // set up the main GUI
        gui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        JToolBar tools = new JToolBar();
        tools.setFloatable(false);
        gui.add(tools, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        tools.add(new JButton("New")); // TODO - add functionality!
        tools.add(new JButton("Save")); // TODO - add functionality!
        tools.add(new JButton("Restore")); // TODO - add functionality!
        tools.addSeparator();
        tools.add(new JButton("Resign")); // TODO - add functionality!
        tools.addSeparator();
        tools.add(message);

        gui.add(new JLabel("?"), BorderLayout.LINE_START);

        chessBoard = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 9));
        chessBoard.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        gui.add(chessBoard);

        // create the chess board squares
        Insets buttonMargin = new Insets(0,0,0,0);
        for (int ii = 0; ii < chessBoardSquares.length; ii++) {
            for (int jj = 0; jj < chessBoardSquares[ii].length; jj++) {
                JButton b = new JButton();
                b.setMargin(buttonMargin);
                // our chess pieces are 64x64 px in size, so we'll
                // 'fill this in' using a transparent icon..
                ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(
                        new BufferedImage(64, 64, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB));
                b.setIcon(icon);
                if ((jj % 2 == 1 && ii % 2 == 1)
                        //) {
                        || (jj % 2 == 0 && ii % 2 == 0)) {
                    b.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                } else {
                    b.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                }
                chessBoardSquares[jj][ii] = b;
            }
        }

        //fill the chess board
        chessBoard.add(new JLabel(""));
        // fill the top row
        for (int ii = 0; ii < 8; ii++) {
            chessBoard.add(
                    new JLabel(COLS.substring(ii, ii + 1),
                    SwingConstants.CENTER));
        }
        // fill the black non-pawn piece row
        for (int ii = 0; ii < 8; ii++) {
            for (int jj = 0; jj < 8; jj++) {
                switch (jj) {
                    case 0:
                        chessBoard.add(new JLabel("" + (ii + 1),
                                SwingConstants.CENTER));
                    default:
                        chessBoard.add(chessBoardSquares[jj][ii]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public final JComponent getChessBoard() {
        return chessBoard;
    }

    public final JComponent getGui() {
        return gui;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                ChessBoardWithColumnsAndRows cb =
                        new ChessBoardWithColumnsAndRows();

                JFrame f = new JFrame("ChessChamp");
                f.add(cb.getGui());
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                f.setLocationByPlatform(true);

                // ensures the frame is the minimum size it needs to be
                // in order display the components within it
                f.pack();
                // ensures the minimum size is enforced.
                f.setMinimumSize(f.getSize());
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: Answers without text tends to be downvoted by the community. Please add some explanation to your code.