# Open anew window using java

Tags: java, javascript

Is there any way to open a new window with a specified URL using java only.I know that we can use window.open in javascript but i need it to be in java page.Anyidea?.

Comment: do you mean, in an applet, running in a browser page?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434483/how-to-open-new-applet-window-from-a-applet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Applet's context and the `showDocument()` method.
Example:

```
String link = "http://www.google.com";
URL u = new URL(link);
AppletContext a = getAppletContext();
a.showDocument(u,"_self");
```

You can change the window/tab opening the link by changing the `_self` to `_blank`

Answer (score 0):

If it's indeed an applet, and you want to create a **Java** window (`JFrame` or similar), see AlphaMale's comment.

If what you want instead is a new **browser** window, you can either follow inquizitive's answer, or alternatively use [`JSObject`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/invokingJavaScriptFromApplet.html) to run arbitrary JavaScript code:

```
import netscape.javascript.*; // add plugin.jar to classpath during compilation

...

JSObject window = JSObject.getWindow(this);
window.eval('window.open(url)');
```

This is more useful to interact with the page's scripts, of course, if what you want is just open another tab using the Applet API may be simpler.