# Can i make more than one graphics console in Java?

Tags: java, graphics

I want to make a graphics based game (applet) which opens a second graphics console when a user clicks a button on the first console. Is there anyway I can do this? I tried to add the main method to the game so that I can import hsa.Console and create a console by doing:

Console myConsole= new Console (15, 30, "My Console");

but when I click 'run' on the IDE it gives me the option to either run the program as an applet or an application. Please help! Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434483/how-to-open-new-applet-window-from-a-applet) answer your question?

Comment: Note that `hsa.Console` is not part of the standard Java libraries - seems to be part of the defunct Ready to Program IDE by Holtsoft?

Comment: I think that this is probably the proper way to do it...I am using a very old version of Java for my computer science class (v. 1.7?). Is there a way to do it without using frames? Yes, I am using ready to program!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make another class in the same folder and let the first one run the second when a button is clicked. If you want any example/ more details/or anything you don't understand, just leave a comment

Comment: Thank you so much, I think this is a perfect solution to what I'm trying to do!

Comment: :) thought of it one day in my dreams when I first started writing Java! By the way, I don't know why this got me stuck for so long back then, but if you wanted to lets say give some information from one class to another, you know you could do int(or whatever other data type) DataName= TheClassWithData.TheNameOfTheDataYouWantInThatClass;